# TWebBrowser how set caret position to end of INPUT(text) field on IE8

Tags: delphi, input, twebbrowser

I have an application that loads a webpage via TWebBrowser and on this page I have some HTML inputs. What I want is to change the value of an input and set the caret position to the end.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
procedure SetInputValue(Document : IHTMLDocument2; const ElementId, NewValue : String);

var Doc   : IHTMLDocument3;
    El    : IHTMLElement;

begin
 Doc := Document as IHTMLDocument3;
 if Assigned(Doc) then
  begin
   El := Doc.getElementById(ElementId);
   if Assigned(El) then
    begin
     if El.tagName = 'INPUT' then
      (El as IHTMLInputElement).Value := NewValue;
      (El as IHTMLInputElement).select;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

This piece of code sets the input value and highlights the text portion.
I am aware of the [IHTMLInputTextElement2 Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975487%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but it is only available from IE9

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `IHTMLTxtRange`

```
var Tr: IHTMLTxtRange;

Tr := (El as IHTMLInputElement).createTextRange;
Tr.collapse(true);
Tr.moveEnd('character', Length(NewValue));
Tr.moveStart('character', Length(NewValue));
Tr.select();
```